# Vega-lite reset view using vega-embed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vega-lite

I am new to using vegalite and trying to integrate a chart on my webpage using vega-embed like below :

```
embed('#viewchart', this.spec)
```

where this.spec data is set from an API. However, I noticed the chart displays old data when the API call fails and no new data is found. Is there a way to reset the vega-embed view every time embed() is called? I tried resetting with empty spec like below but that doesn't seem to work.

```
embed('#viewchart', {} )
```

Comment: So as I understand, you already have a spec rendered with some data and you just want to add new data by replacing the old data. If this is your use case then you should remove your data using the 'view.change' API. In that you can remove old data and insert the new data. Refer to the API in here: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_change

Comment: Thanks @wahabmemon for pointing to the view.change link, it was helpful to know. However, in my case the issue was with the handling of backend API response. I added couple of checks on the response code and enabled chart display only when data is available which resolved the issue.